# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when running cyclic ES6 imports in Jest

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs

While writing some test suites for some ES6 modules, I discovered that Jest v26.6 runs into errors when trying to do some cyclic imports.

The problem can be reduced to the following:

ClassA.mjs

```
import {B} from './ClassB.mjs';

class A {
    constructor()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

ClassB.mjs

```
import {A} from './ClassA.mjs';

class B extends A {
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Cyclic.test.js

```
import {B} from "./ClassB.mjs";

describe('Cyclic', () => {
    test('Cyclic', () => {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Jest exits with a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error message, at different places of its source, depending on the imports of the test.

Are there any solutions to this, any known workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By default Jest uses CommonJS that wasn't designed for cyclic deps. Jest support for native ESM is incomplete and useless ATM. So avoid CD.

Comment: A should not import B, which will remove the cyclical issue. B is going to extend A, so A really should not have a reference to B.

Comment: This isn't exactly a solution, but if you have other trouble using Jest to test ESM code, you can usually solve that by telling Jest to transform the code to CJS using Babel before running the tests. The plugin is "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"

Answer (score 0):

I was also seeing this with Jest version 26 using `NODE_OPTIONS='--experimental-vm-modules'`. When I updated to Jest version 27 (27.5.1), the errors went away.

With Jest version 26, my errors looked like:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Exception in PromiseRejectCallback:
internal/vm/module.js:321
        const module = await linker(identifier, this);
```